# Is there a way to trigger windows.focus() while using chrome in headless mode?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to trigger windows.focus() on one of my tests that is running in a headless environment. But I'm having trouble getting it to work. Although, the test seems to work when I turn off the headless mode setting. So far I've tried the following but to no avail:

1. `js.executeScript("windows.blur()")` before windows.focus()
2. Force setting windows resolution before windows.focus()
3. Focussing/clicking on specific element  (`js.executeScript("document.getElementById('reactRoot').focus();");`)

Was wondering if there's something I'm missing in my setup.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  The window's focus won't affect the webdriver... for instance if you click a link that opens a new tab and set the focus to that new tab, the webdriver will still be operating in the original tab.  (the driver's actions will set focus in DOM not window... the driver's current window/tab is determined by the window handle...so use the webdriver's switchTo method to switch to another window/tab.)

Comment: I actually have only one window/tab in play for this scenario. Let's say I have a listener that's waiting for some sort of activity such as windows.focus() to occur on my page.  Currently, for whatever reason its not able to pick up the focussing activity on my window/tab in headless mode. I don't know if opening a new tab is what I want to be doing.

Comment: Your normal webdriver actions should create those focus events which should bubble up...  there is however another type of event for whether the browser itself is in front/visible on desktop... for that you'd need to create an event of visibilitychange... but I don't know that it is possible to do that... I'm not even sure what headless does with the visibilitystate... maybe check here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event